# React - should Higher Order Component be written as a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I'm learning React. It seems to me that HOC like the following example from React's official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

```
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectData) {
    // ...and returns another component...
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.state = {
                data: selectData(DataSource, props)
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            // ... that takes care of the subscription...
            DataSource.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            DataSource.removeChangeListener(this.handleChange);
        }

        handleChange() {
            this.setState({
                data: selectData(DataSource, this.props)
            });
        }

        render() {
            // ... and renders the wrapped component with the fresh data!
            // Notice that we pass through any additional props
            return <WrappedComponent data={this.state.data} {...this.props} />;
        }
    };
}
```

can be rewritten in this way:

```
class WithSubscription extends React.Component {
    constructor({ component, selectData, ...props }) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            data: selectData(DataSource, props)
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        DataSource.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        DataSource.removeChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    }

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({
            data: selectData(DataSource, this.props)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <component data={this.state.data} {...this.props} />;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

`<WithSubscription component={BlogPost} selectData={(DataSource) => DataSource.getComments()} />`

Are they both HOC? When is one style preferred than the other?

Comment: you asked a question. then modified it after it was answered, then argued even when presented with the definition of an HoC.  your question was why was your component not an HoC not the differences btween the patterns. Make a question at a time that will hep you to get better answers and people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: I didn't change my question. It's just one small error in my code unintentionally. See what I edited you'll understand.

Comment: reactstrap uses a similar pattern which I've found useful, where you can pass in a tag attribute that is a component, but that's just used for rendering rather than highjacking props: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/Button.js#L12

Comment: what is highjacking props? Any reference?

Comment: i just was referring to adding additional props to the component, like how you add the data prop above.  this is a useful article if you haven't read it yet: https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling with HOC too at first. Another way of looking at this is at wrappers of components that you could use to isolate the functionality from one component.

For example, I have multiple HOC. I have many components that are only defined by props, and they are immutable once they are created.

Then I have a Loader HOC Component, which handles all the network connectivity and then just passes the props to whatever component is wrapping (This would be the component you pass to the HOC).

The loader does not really care which component it is rendering, it only needs to fetch data, and pass it to the wrapped component.

In your example, you can actually accomplish the same, however it will become much more complex once you need to chain multiple HOC.

For example I have this chain of HOCs:

PermissionsHOC -> LoaderHOC -> BorderLayoutHOC -> Component

First one can check your permissions, second one is loading the data, third one is giving a generic layout and the forth one is the actual component.

It is much easier to detect HOCs if you realize that some components would benefit from having a generic logic on the parent. You could do the same in your example, however you would need to modify the HOC every time you add a child component, to add the logic for that one. Not very effective. This way, you can add new components easily. I do have a Base component which every component extends, but I use it to handle the helper functions like analytics, logger, handling errors, etc.

Comment: I think this is the main advantage of standard HOCS over the OPs suggested approach, HOC composition is much easier this way.

Comment: This is indeed an advantage.

Comment: It is much easier to detect HOCs if you realize that some components would benefit from having a generic logic on the parent. You could do the same in your example, however you would need to modify the HOC every time you add a child component, to add the logic for that one. Not very effective. This way, you can add new components easily. I do have a Base component which every component extends, but I use it to handle the helper functions like analytics, logger, handling errors, etc.

Comment: One last thing, I have another component that actually wraps the components based on props, that way I decide if I need to add the loader to the component (if the data comes remotely) or the permissions (if I need the location enabled to show this component, for example). Spend some days playing with them, it is a struggle but it is worth it.

Comment: Why I need to modify my second HOC every time I add a child component? It can be generic too just like the first HOC, right?

Comment: As it is right now you are right. I was thinking if you eventually add methods for the child components but i guess if you only use it to load data is fine.

Answer (score 2):

What they call an "HOC" is basically a function (just a regular function, not React specific) that behaves like component factory. Meaning it outputs wrapped components that are the **result** of wrapping any inside-component *of your choice*. And your choice is specified with the "WrappedComponent" parameter. (Notice how their so-called "HOC" actually returns a class).

So I don't know why they called it an "HOC" tbh. It's just a function that spits out components. If anyone knows why I'd be interested in hearing the reason.

In essence their example is doing exactly what you're doing, but it's more flexible because WrappedComponent is being taken in as a parameter. So you can specify whatever you want. 
 
 Your code, on the other hand, has your inside component hard coded into it.

To see the power of their example, let's say you have a file called insideComp.js containing:

```
import withSubscription from './withSubscription';

class InsideComp extends React.Component{
// define it
}

export default withSubscription(InsideComp);
```

And when you use insideComp in another file:

```
import myComp from './insideComp.js';
```

You're not actually importing insideComp, but rather the wrapped version that "withSubscription" had already spit out. Because remember your last line of insideComp.js is

```
export default withSubscription(InsideComp);
```

So your InsideComp was modified before it was exported

Answer (score 1):

The second one is not a HOC.

They coin the word HOC from [higher order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). One example of a higher order function is a function that takes a function as an argument and returns another function.

Similarly, a HOC is a function that takes an component as argument and returns another component.

This does sound weird to me because a higher order component is not a react component; it is a function instead. I guess the reason they call it HOC is because:

A react component is a class, which is indeed a constructor function in JavaScript (except that functional components are simply functions). A HOC actually takes a function (a constructor function) and returns another function (another constructor function), so it is actually a higher order function if you think about it. Probably because it is in the react context and this is a pattern to transform components, they call it HOC.

As to the difference between the two styles you mentioned:

First one: you would use the first one to generate a class like `MyComponnet = withSubscription(AnotherComponent, ...)`, and whenever you need it in a render call just write `<MyComponent><MyComponent>`

Second one: this is less common. Every time you need it in a render call, you would need to include the WithSubscription component as you mentioned in the description `<WithSubscription component={BlogPost} selectData={(DataSource) => DataSource.getComments()} />`

Comment: HoC *is* a component, it's not the factory function/wrapper, it *is* the new function/closure you returned which should be a react component.

Comment: agree the term is bit confusing though since it's not of any valid react component (class/functional).